# Unable to build a Haskell program using cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I am trying to learn Haskell with Atom ide on windows 7. I can build a program with stack but not with cabal. I wouldn't care about this except that Atom uses cabal. When I enter the command 'cabal build' I get the following messages: "Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this fails please run configure manually." "cabal: The program 'ghc' version >=6.4 is required but it could not be found." I have ghc version 7.10.3 installed which is >=6.4. So I guess it can't find the ghc compiler. Could somebody please advise?

Comment: I would recommend setting up atom to use stack (should be possible: https://github.com/atom-haskell/ide-haskell/issues/82)

Comment: Is GHC in your system path?

Comment: What happens if you just run `ghc` from the command line?

Comment: There is no GHC environment variable and I am unable to run ghc from the command line.

Comment: I guess the question is - Where does stack install ghc? Once I know this I can add it to the path and all should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out where stack installs ghc by running `stack path --ghc-paths`.